# Microsoft Command Line Linker can't find 'libcpmt.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

However, when (using Cygwin) I type `which libcpmt.lib`, it displays the correct path.  I've not been able to compile using any command line (cmd.exe, Cygwin, or the Developer Command Prompt for VS2013).  However, if I make a VS project and import my source files, everything works fine.

The error I get is `fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libcpmt.lib'`

Complete output:

```
cl src/MyMesh.cpp src/MyMeshTest.cpp src/Affine.cpp /Febin/mesh
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.30501 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

MyMesh.cpp
MyMeshTest.cpp
Affine.cpp
Generating Code...
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 12.00.30501.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:bin/mesh.exe
MyMesh.obj
MyMeshTest.obj
Affine.obj
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libcpmt.lib'
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

I've set up the system environment variables like so:

**INCLUDE**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt
```

**LIB**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\lib;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10150.0\ucrt\x86;
```

**LIBPATH**

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10150.0\ucrt\x86;
```

(Spaces have been added for readability)

Any obvious issues here?  I'm running Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: You haven't mentioned exact error which you are getting.

Comment: Also, type here exact command line

Comment: Sorry about that, I've now edited in the error to my original question--`fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libcpmt.lib'`.  What did you want me to do with the command line?

Comment: Specify additional include directory to compiler: link /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib"

Comment: Something has definitely gone wrong somewhere in my configuration.  I compiled with cl, then used the _absolute path_ to link, whereupon it worked both with and without the /LIBPATH option.  Very strange--I'm going to work on diagnosing the issue later tonight.  Thank you for your assistance, though--without that I never would have tried running the linker by itself.